# Scrapy-Splash not rendering html

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to pull the images from this website:
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3205-Peavy-Dr-Austin-TX-78725/29462707_zpid/
but was not able to access the images as they seemed to only be accessible after the site rendered. I implemented scrapy-splash to try to download these images, and after setting up the docker container and testing in scrapy shell, it seems to be working:

`fetch('http://0.0.0.0:8050/render.html?url=https%2F%2Fwww.zillow.com%2Fhomedetails%2F3205-Peavy-Dr-Austin-TX-78725%2F29462707_zpid%2F') 2023-04-15 14:53:08 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: KqueueSelector 2023-04-15 14:53:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2023-04-15 14:53:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://0.0.0.0:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2023-04-15 14:53:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://0.0.0.0:8050/render.html?url=https%2F%2Fwww.zillow.com%2Fhomedetails%2F3205-Peavy-Dr-Austin-TX-78725%2F29462707_zpid%2F> (referer: None)`

However, when I print response.body, I get this:
`b'<html><head></head><body></body></html>'`

I've set the user_agent in settings.py to prevent getting blocked by the site? I haven't used scrapy-splash before and I can't think of other ways to troubleshoot. Is anyone able to offer insight or additional things I could try to get the full html here?

Comment: create a [mre].